# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mysqli.so'

Tags: php, mysqli

I Got this error. I already search on google for 2 days but problem is still there.

Error msg :

```
[20-Mar-2014 08:48:00 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mysqli.so' - libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0]
```

Code :

```
$flmconn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
    if(! $flmconn )
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($flmconn, $db_name);
    if (!$db_select) 
        {
            die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
        }
    $sql= mysqli_query($flmconn, "select * from gallery");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $sql, MYSQL_ASSOC )) 
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $thumb = $row['thumb'];
        $pic = $row['pic'];
```

Other queries work correctly :

```
$sql= mysqli_query($flmconn, "select * from partner");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $sql, MYSQL_ASSOC )) 
    {
        $heading = $row['heading'];
        $text = $row['text'];
        $pic = $row['text_pic'];
```

Comment: did you install mysqli extension (sudo apt-get install php5-mysql if you use Ubuntu/Debian OS)?

Comment: I don't know.... on local computer it works correctaly but on server error appears. also other queries works fine.

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: How can you not know whether you installed it or not? It's never installed by default, so you _must_ install it

Comment: But other queries works correctly without any prob. Only this single query give errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time back, but problem is in

```
MYSQL_ASSOC
```

instead of

```
MYSQL_ASSOC
```

need to use

```
MYSQLI_ASSOC
```